# Multplying rows in pandas and adding to an iteration

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'Week' : ['WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'WK4', 'WK5']})
print(df)
        ID  Week
0   1   WK1
1   2   WK2
2   3   WK3
3   4   WK4
4   5   WK5
```

what would be the most Pythonic way to loop and duplicate each row whilst adding +1 to the week number,

so based on the first two values, this would be my desired result.

```
   ID   Week
0   1   WK1
1   1   WK2
2   1   WK3
3   1   WK4
4   1   WK5
5   2   WK1
6   2   WK2
7   2   WK3
8   2   WK4
9   2   WK5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Cartesian product.  Use a comprehension and reconstruct your `DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame([(i, w) for i in df.ID for w in df.Week], columns=df.columns)

    ID Week
0    1  WK1
1    1  WK2
2    1  WK3
3    1  WK4
4    1  WK5
5    2  WK1
6    2  WK2
7    2  WK3
8    2  WK4
9    2  WK5
10   3  WK1
11   3  WK2
12   3  WK3
13   3  WK4
14   3  WK5
15   4  WK1
16   4  WK2
17   4  WK3
18   4  WK4
19   4  WK5
20   5  WK1
21   5  WK2
22   5  WK3
23   5  WK4
24   5  WK5
```

Same as

```
# empty list
a = []

for i in df.ID:
    for w in df.Week:
        a.append((i, w))

pd.DataFrame(a, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Would this be possible in a simple(er) for loop? I just want to understand all the steps, I was using df.append but couldn't work out the incrementation. Don't understand your caretisian point, I'll have to whip out my old uni notes from philosophy!

Comment: "I think, therefore I am" is not the Descartes contribution I was referring to.  He was also a mathematician and invented the x, y axis we refer to as the Cartesian Plane.  A Cartesian product is the set of all combinations of multiple sets.  Also referred to as a cross product.

Comment: I achieve all combinations with the double `for` in the comprehension.

Comment: I'm certain there is a way.  I suspect using `enumerate` would help (or many other things).  The problem is that I'm not quite sure of what you're asking.  Read [mcve] and ask a new question showing what you want and explaining how you get there.  I'm sure your question will be answered promptly.  To provide a few more specifics about my confusion, I don't know what defines how many times I should iterate per row.  Do I restart iteraration for new values of a certain column?

Comment: Also, I could also probably point you to questions and answers that already exist if I just understood better what you mean.

Comment: yeah I thought it would be better as a new question as it's not really fair to ask that in a comment. Thanks for your help good sir.

Comment: many thanks for this again, only now really understand the code and logic behind your answer. Very neat, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `unstack` with `bfill` and `ffill`

```
df.set_index('ID',append=True).Week.unstack().ffill(1).bfill(1).stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=1)
Out[1025]: 
   ID    0
0   1  WK1
1   1  WK2
2   1  WK3
3   1  WK4
4   1  WK5
0   2  WK1
1   2  WK2
2   2  WK3
3   2  WK4
4   2  WK5
0   3  WK1
1   3  WK2
2   3  WK3
3   3  WK4
4   3  WK5
0   4  WK1
1   4  WK2
2   4  WK3
3   4  WK4
4   4  WK5
0   5  WK1
1   5  WK2
2   5  WK3
3   5  WK4
4   5  WK5
```